# Hello world app fails in as giving error Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: java, android

I tried using  `multiDexEnabled` true and clean ,rebuild but i get severe build error. thanks in advance. am blocked due to this
below is list of errors:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Exception in thread \"main\" ","sources":[{}]}

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Exception in thread \"main\" ","sources":[{}]}
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task '`:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug`'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
  >   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` that's the error you need to be searching for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that multidex isn't needed on any "hello world" apps. When you need multidex, you'll likely get an error telling you that you actually do need it.